# Is there any way to git rid of circular dependency in from angular dependency injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, circular-dependency

How can I get rid from circular dependency injection error in Angular 1.x ?

I know I can use injector to inject some service.

But is it the only way around ?

Also, is it OK to use this in application?

Comment: alternative is restructuring dependencies...not enough details provided beyond that. See [ask]

Comment: if you have circular dependencies, you’re doing something wrong ;) Provide some code samples so we can help you fix this !

Answer (score 2):

Miško Hevery, has a blog post explaining the issue and how to circumvent this problem. [blog](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/01/circular-dependency-in-constructors-and-dependency-injection/)
TD;LR 
There is a third service hidden inside the first or the second service which is needed by the two services.

Comment: Can you post a code snippet or more expanded explanation? Links rot so in order to keep this answer useful, would be good to copy the most important part of the blog here.